# Export Appointment to outlook using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using addeventatc. As per research i have to use addeventatc.refresh(); after page page loaded because i am using data from api call.It works if i put button on my screen. But not working with loading.

Here website https://www.addevent.com/add-to-calendar-button .

```
    <tr ng-repeat="y in x.LEAVE_DAYS | orderBy:'LEAVE_DATE'">
                                                <td>
    <span ng-show="test" title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
    <br />
    <span class="start">{{y.LEAVE_START | date:'M/d/yy h:mm a'}}</span>
    <span class="end">{{y.LEAVE_END | date:'M/d/yy h:mm a'}}</span>
    <span class="timezone">US/Arizona</span>
    <span class="title">Time Approved for {{x.REQ_TYPE}}</span>
    <span class="description">Approved Hours :  {{y.HOURS}}</span>
     </span>
     </td>
```

I tried as below its work. But i do want to fire this function after my table load on screen.

```
button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="testing(); test=true">&nbsp Exports data</button>
```

controller

```
  $scope.testing = function () {
    addeventatc.refresh();
}
```

Comment: what is the api call? can you call addeventatc.refresh(); after you get the data?

Comment: i tried but not working.

Comment: I am assuming x.LEAVE_DAYS is an array. One possible quick solution may be to use a div to wrap the html with an ng-if="x.LEVE_DAYS.length > 0"

Comment: Yes x.LEAVE_DAYS is Array. Can you tell where should in use ng-if. I used but not working.

Comment: x.LEAVE_DAYS are always greater then 0

Comment: it is better to see more code. Can you post your api call function? and how you call refresh in the api call?

Comment: $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'api/testing/' + $scope.user,            
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {         
            $scope.requestData = data.REQs; 
            addeventatc.refresh();
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "An error has occured  (" + status + ")";          
        });

Comment: you are updating $scope.requestData, which is not used in the html. How are you gonna use requestData in the js? can you post it too?

Comment: <tbody ng-repeat="x in requestData>

Comment: My code is really long.

Comment: try wrap it with a ng-if like this <div ng-if="requestData.length > 0"><tbody ng-repeat=x....>...</tbody></div>

Comment: same issue. Did not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have any example. how we can export data or json to outlook using angularjs.

Comment: sorry I don't have one with me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
   addeventatc.refresh();
}, 200);
```